# Why doesn't my App list my Settings?

Tags: ios, swift2, settings.bundle, xcode7-beta6

I've added the stock 'Settings.Bundle' into my App Bundle:

[image]

However, I get a different set of settings (shown in simulator): 
[image]

*** Revision ***
The Settings.bundle is a member of the target:
[image]

Here's where the settings.bundle is located:
[image]

**Note:** I can see the new Settings after I do a 'reset' of the Simulator. 
However I don't see any change on the actual device, even after removing the app and doing a cold restart.

How do I get my **DEVICE version** to recognize the updated/new Settings bundle?

Comment: Is your bundle selected for inclusion with your target?

Comment: I have the Settings.bundle within the 'Copy Bundle Resources' of the build, generated automatically; if that's what you mean.

Comment: I've updated the Xcode IDE to version 7 GM.    I made sure Settings @ root and is member of target.    I've rested the simulator.   I *works* upon rebuild on Simulator.   However, nothing changed with DEVICE: removed app and re-install & run... no change in Settings (see above rewrite).   Why?

Comment: There's also a bug causing the settings to disappear all the time. Kill the settings app to fix this. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/9853

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two requirements are:

- Settings.bundle must be included in your target

[image]

- Settings.bundle should be in the root of your app folder/bundle

Comment: It worked! But one thing I did not understand is that the app usually gets added to the settings app when it is installed then why it is necessary to add this bundle?

Answer (score 3):

Issue fixed,after relaunching the settings app.

Answer (score 1):

Both of Dan's suggestions were needed to be on the right track.  However as with having to reset the simulator to get the Settings to function correctly,  I had to:

1) Remove the device app. 
2) Do a cold restart of the device, 
3) Re-install the revised-Setting application.

Once I did all that, I can see the revised Setting changes.

Answer (score 0):

I was using CloudKit. The app appeared in the Settings app only after the app accessed CloudKit through:

```
[[CKContainer defaultContainer] accountStatusWithCompletionHandler:^(CKAccountStatus accountStatus, NSError *error) {
```

That makes sense. Try to use the function that requires some sort of permission suitable for inclusion in the Settings app